# Unable to scroll two collectionviews horizontally at a time in swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I have two collectionviews in scrollview. if i scroll horizontally then I need both collectionviews scroll at a time

**code:** in below code if i scroll first collectionview then 1st collectionview first cell scrolling then 2nd collectionview's cell scrolling. but i need both collectionviews scroll at a time

here `qrCollectionView` and `adCollectionView` are two collectionviews

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
if scrollView.isEqual(qrCollectionView), scrollView.isDragging {
       var offset = adCollectionView.contentOffset
       offset.x = qrCollectionView.contentOffset.x
    adCollectionView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: true)
   } else if scrollView.isEqual(adCollectionView), scrollView.isDragging {
       var offset = qrCollectionView.contentOffset
       offset.x = adCollectionView.contentOffset.x
       qrCollectionView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: true)
   }
}
```

need like this: if i use two buttons then its working perfect.. i need like this when i manually scroll not buttontap, how? please guide me

```
@IBAction func leftButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

if currentItem != 0, currentItem != nil {

    currentItem! -= 1
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentItem!, section: 0)
    qrCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    adCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)

} else {
    print("No item to go to previous left")
}
}

@IBAction func rightButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

guard let totalItems = ticketListtData?.result?.tickets?.count else { return }
if currentItem! < totalItems - 1 {
    currentItem! += 1
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentItem!, section: 0)
    qrCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    adCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)

} else {
    print("No item to go to next right")
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let assume your both collection view have same contentOffset.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == qrCollectionView {
            adCollectionView.contentOffset.x = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        }else {
            qrCollectionView.contentOffset.x = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        }
    }
```

For me it's working fine. be sure that scrollViewDidScroll is calling every time while scrolling.

Comment: thank you, now scrollview scrolling horizontally but we need to scroll collectionview cell wise

Comment: I mean once i scroll it has to stop for every one cell both collectionview together.. your code is completely scrolling from first to last without any break between cells